# Inject JNDI resources into a collection property of EJB

Tags: dependency-injection, resources, ejb, jndi

I have a stateless EJB which contains multiple JNDI Resources that should be injected:

```
@Stateless(name = "QueueDispatcher")
public class QueueDispatcher {  
    @Resource(name = "jms/syncQueue1")
    private Queue queue1;    
    @Resource(name = "jms/syncQueue2")
    private Queue queue2;
    ...

    private List<Queue> queueList;  

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //Move injected queues into arraylist...
        queueList = new ArrayList<Queue>();
        if(queue1 != null){ queueList.add(queue1); }
        if(queue2 != null){ queueList.add(queue2); }
        ...
    }
}
```

My current implementation uses multiple fields to receive injected resources and then moves them into a Collection for subsequent use.

However, this code is ugly and the number of queues should be dynamic. When I have to increase the number of queues, I don't want to change the code on multiple places but instead simply add a single configuration line/annotation.

Is there a way configure stateless beans so that Resources are directly injected into the List? I'm using EJB 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Resource` can't be bind to a list, but you can use a string list with all resources like `jms/syncQueue2,jms/syncQueue2` then in `@PostCostruct` you can do a dynamic lookup.

```
@Resource(name = "myqueues")
private String queues;

...

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Context ctx=new InitialContext();
    String[] list = queues.split(",");
    for(String item : list) {
        try { 
            Queue q = (Queue) ctx.lookup(item);
            queueList.add(q);
        }
    }
}
```

complete the code with catch ecc.